# How to add 10 specific products (objects) with different data types in each one, in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, object

I am a newbie in java and I'm trying to create a vending machine but I can't seem to be able to add 10 products that I need. (I'm using BlueJ for coding as requested by my instructor). I  need the machine to be able to display the available products only, let the user buy products, display total money in the machine and display the total items sold!

Here is my object code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class VendingMachineObject {

       public String productName = "";
       public double unitPrice;
       public int initialQuantity;
       public int availableQuantity;

       public VendingMachineObject(String newProductName, double newUnitPrice, int newInitialQuantity, int newAvailableQuantity) {
           this.productName = newProductName;
           this.unitPrice = newUnitPrice;
           this.initialQuantity = newInitialQuantity;
           this.availableQuantity = newAvailableQuantity;
       }

       public String getProductName() {
           return this.productName;
       }

       public double getUnitPrice() {
           return this.unitPrice;
       }

       public int getInitialQuantity() {
           return this.initialQuantity;
       }

       public int getAvailableQuantity() {
           return this.availableQuantity;
       }

       public void setProductName(String newProductName) {
           this.productName = newProductName;
       }

       public void setUnitPrice(double newUnitPrice) {
          this.unitPrice = newUnitPrice;
       }

       public void setInitialQuantity(int newInitialQuantity) {
           this.initialQuantity = newInitialQuantity;
       }

       public void setAvailableQuantity(int newAvailableQuantity) {
           this.availableQuantity = newAvailableQuantity;
       }
}
```

And the main app code:

```
public class VendingMachine {

   static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   static ArrayList<VendingMachineObject> myVendor = new ArrayList<VendingMachineObject>(10);

   static public int soldProductsCounter = 0;

   static public double totalMoneyCounter = 0;


   public static void main (String args[]) {

        int choice;

        do {
        displayMenu();
        choice = input.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1: displayAvailableProducts(myVendor);
                break;
        case 2: buyProduct(myVendor);
                break;
        case 3: displayTotalProductsSold(myVendor);
                break;
        case 4: displayTotalMoney(myVendor);
                break;
        case 5: System.out.println("End of program");
                break;
        default: System.out.println("Invalid option. Try again.");

        }


        } while (choice != 5);

      System.exit(0);

   }

   public static void displayMenu() {

    System.out.println("1. Display available products");

    System.out.println("2. Buy a product");

    System.out.println("3. Display the total products sold");

    System.out.println("4. Display the total money in the machine");

    System.out.println("5. Exit");

    System.out.println("Choice ?");
   }

   public static void displayAvailableProducts(ArrayList<VendingMachineObject> myVendor) {

        int availableQuantity;

        for (VendingMachineObject x: myVendor) {
            if(x.getAvailableQuantity() > 0) {
                System.out.println(x.getProductName() + " " + x.getUnitPrice() + " " + x.getAvailableQuantity());
            }
        }
   }

   public static void buyProduct(ArrayList<VendingMachineObject> myVendor) {

       String productName;

       int availableQuantity;

       int choice;

       System.out.println("Which product do you want to buy?");

       productName = input.next();

       for (VendingMachineObject x: myVendor) {

           if (x.getProductName() == productName) {

               System.out.println("The cost of this product is:" + x.getUnitPrice());

               System.out.println("Items in stock:" + x.getAvailableQuantity());

               System.out.println("How many do you want to buy?");

               choice = input.nextInt();

               if (choice > x.getAvailableQuantity()) {

                System.out.println("You can not buy so many products");

                System.out.println("You can buy only:" + x.getAvailableQuantity());

                choice = x.getAvailableQuantity();

            }

            System.out.println("The total cost is:" + (choice * x.getUnitPrice()));

            x.setAvailableQuantity(x.getAvailableQuantity()-choice);

            soldProductsCounter = soldProductsCounter + choice;

            totalMoneyCounter = totalMoneyCounter + x.getUnitPrice();

        }
       } 
   }

   public static void displayTotalProductsSold(ArrayList<VendingMachineObject> myVendor) {

       System.out.println("Items sold:" + " " + soldProductsCounter);

   }

   public static void displayTotalMoney(ArrayList<VendingMachineObject> myVendor) {

       System.out.println("Total money in the machine:" + " "+ totalMoneyCounter);

   }
}
```

Comment: EDIT: the correct declaration for the list is:

ArrayList<VendingMachineObject> myVendor = new ArrayList<VendingMachineObject>(10);

Comment: And what is the question? You already have a suitable type for buyable objects from the machine. You only need to create new instances of them with their data (i.e., name, price, ...).

Comment: Thing is that i need the products to be preloaded in the machine through an array... how can i enter 10 custom products (objects) with name, price, initial quantity and available quantity in an array? Other similar articles didnt help me that much.

Comment: Just create a constructor for `VendingMachine` and fill that list there. I still don't know where the problem is.

Comment: that is actually what i am not able to do the whole array and add products thing. and i am not sure if it is better to use an array or an array list.

Comment: VendingMachineObject [] myVendor = new VendingMachineObject[10];


VendingMachineObject product1 = new VendingMachineObject("Coke", 1.50, 10, 10);


myVendor[0] = product1;

even when i try it likes this i get an error ']' expected right after the myVendor[    (before the zero after the bracket).

Comment: Use the `Arraylist` and you can add products like this: `myVendor.add(new VendingMachineObject("Soda", 2.0, 5, 5));`. You could use the structure Limantara suggested, but you could also doing this with your current classes.

Comment: `even when i try it likes this i get an error ']' expected right after the myVendor[` because you wrote the directly in the class and not in a method or a constructor.

Comment: Oh so i need to put it in what kind of constructor? like under the VendingMachineObject constructor? (its the one that sets the type and the data in my products)

Comment: in what method? and where? in the main class or the one for the object constructor?(by the way sorry for asking so many questions :<)

Comment: FOUND HOW TO ADD THEM :D thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The products (objects) have to inherit from one superclass.

Suppose you have class `Foods`, `Drinks`, and `Snacks` such that `Drinks` and `Snacks` inherit from `Foods`

You can do this:

```
ArrayList<Foods> menu = new ArrayList<Foods>(10);
menu.add(new Drinks("Coke", 1.99, 10, 10));
menu.add(new Snacks("Candy", 0.99, 10, 10));
```

The above is called Polymorphism, great tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xw06loTm1k

Comment: Thanks! im trying this right now! the "Foods" class is the Main right?

Comment: Doesn't matter where you want to put the `main` method as long as you only have one `main`. But, I see you already have `main` in your `VendingMachine` class, so just leave it that way. Just create separate class for `Foods`, `Drinks`, and `Snacks`

Comment: I have created a VendingMachineObject class where i have the variable types and such just as it is presented above, but i keep getting the identifier expected error after the ".add" :(

Comment: VendingMachineObject [] myVendor = new VendingMachineObject[10];


VendingMachineObject product1 = new VendingMachineObject("Coke", 1.50, 10, 10);

myVendor[0] = product1;
 



even when i try it likes this i get an error ']' expected right after the myVendor[ (before the zero after the bracket).

Comment: Are you using ArrayList or Array? ArrayList is a class, you can't access myVendor[0] like that! see available methods here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html Is this homework assignment? If yes, you definitely need to learn these things if you want to pass the class

Comment: i know! i just want to show you that i tried both methods with list and array and i get different errors in each one. but the VendingMachineObject which is the actual constructor for my products seems to be fine isnt it?

Comment: Just inherit `Drinks` and `Snacks` from `VendingMachineObject` you should be good to go